# Почему не собирается проект из .c и .cpp файлов? ("undefined reference to ...")

Tags: c++, c, сборка, link

Есть файл dbeng.c (своя простенькая обертка к sqlite3):

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "dbeng.h"

sqlite3 *db;

int dbinit(const char *dbname, char * errout)
{
    if( SQLITE_OK != sqlite3_open(dbname, &db) )
    {
        sprintf(errout, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int sqlexec(char *sqlexpr, char * errout, int (*p)(void*,int,char**,char**))
{
    char *zErrMsg = 0;
    if( SQLITE_OK != sqlite3_exec(db, sqlexpr, p, 0, &zErrMsg))
    {
        sprintf(errout, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int dbclose()
{
    return (SQLITE_OK == sqlite3_close(db));
}
```

заголовочный файл dbeng.h:

```
#ifndef DBENG_H_INCLUDED
#define DBENG_H_INCLUDED

int dbinit(const char *dbname, char * errout);
int sqlexec(char *sqlexpr, char * errout, int (*p)(void*,int,char**,char**));
int dbclose();

#endif // DBENG_H_INCLUDED
```

Почему то если компилятор файла выбран СС сборка с остальным проектом (на С++) в Code::Blocks заканчивается неудачей (хотя сам файл успешно компилируется как код на C):
    -------------- Build: Debug in wxdb003 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

```
mingw32-g++.exe -pipe -mthreads -D__GNUWIN32__ -D__WXMSW__ -DWXUSINGDLL -DwxUSE_UNICODE -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Winvalid-pch -include wx_pch.h -DWX_PRECOMP -Wall -g -D__WXDEBUG__ -IC:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\include -IC:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\lib\gcc_dll\mswud -c C:\myproj\wxdb003\wx_pch.h -o wx_pch.h.gch\Debug_myproj_wxdb003_wx_pch_h_gch
mingw32-gcc.exe -c C:\sqlite3\sqlite3.c -o obj\Debug\sqlite3\sqlite3.o
mingw32-gcc.exe -c C:\myproj\wxdb003\dbeng.c -o obj\Debug\myproj\wxdb003\dbeng.o
windres.exe -IC:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\include -IC:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\lib\gcc_dll\mswud  -J rc -O coff -i C:\myproj\wxdb003\resource.rc -o obj\Debug\myproj\wxdb003\resource.res
mingw32-g++.exe -pipe -mthreads -D__GNUWIN32__ -D__WXMSW__ -DWXUSINGDLL -DwxUSE_UNICODE -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Winvalid-pch -include wx_pch.h -DWX_PRECOMP -Wall -g -D__WXDEBUG__ -IC:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\include -IC:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\lib\gcc_dll\mswud -c C:\myproj\wxdb003\wxdb003App.cpp -o obj\Debug\myproj\wxdb003\wxdb003App.o
mingw32-g++.exe -pipe -mthreads -D__GNUWIN32__ -D__WXMSW__ -DWXUSINGDLL -DwxUSE_UNICODE -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Winvalid-pch -include wx_pch.h -DWX_PRECOMP -Wall -g -D__WXDEBUG__ -IC:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\include -IC:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\lib\gcc_dll\mswud -c C:\myproj\wxdb003\wxdb003Main.cpp -o obj\Debug\myproj\wxdb003\wxdb003Main.o
mingw32-g++.exe -LC:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\lib\gcc_dll -o bin\Debug\wxdb003.exe obj\Debug\sqlite3\sqlite3.o obj\Debug\myproj\wxdb003\dbeng.o obj\Debug\myproj\wxdb003\wxdb003App.o obj\Debug\myproj\wxdb003\wxdb003Main.o  obj\Debug\myproj\wxdb003\resource.res -mthreads  -lwxmsw28ud -mwindows
obj\Debug\myproj\wxdb003\wxdb003Main.o: In function `ZN12wxdb003FrameC2EP8wxWindowi':
C:/myproj/wxdb003/wxdb003Main.cpp:123: undefined reference to `dbinit(char const*, char*)'
obj\Debug\myproj\wxdb003\wxdb003Main.o: In function `ZN12wxdb003Frame7OnCloseER12wxCloseEvent':
C:/myproj/wxdb003/wxdb003Main.cpp:165: undefined reference to `dbclose()'
obj\Debug\myproj\wxdb003\wxdb003Main.o: In function `ZN12wxdb003Frame14OnExecuteClickER14wxCommandEvent':
C:/myproj/wxdb003/wxdb003Main.cpp:176: undefined reference to `sqlexec(char*, char*, int (*)(void*, int, char**, char**))'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 11 second(s))
4 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 11 second(s))
```

Если же задать в качестве компилятора этого файла CPP, то всё успешно собирается:
    -------------- Build: Debug in wxdb003 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

```
mingw32-g++.exe -pipe -mthreads -D__GNUWIN32__ -D__WXMSW__ -DWXUSINGDLL -DwxUSE_UNICODE -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Winvalid-pch -include wx_pch.h -DWX_PRECOMP -Wall -g -D__WXDEBUG__ -IC:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\include -IC:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\lib\gcc_dll\mswud -c C:\myproj\wxdb003\wx_pch.h -o wx_pch.h.gch\Debug_myproj_wxdb003_wx_pch_h_gch
mingw32-gcc.exe -c C:\sqlite3\sqlite3.c -o obj\Debug\sqlite3\sqlite3.o
mingw32-g++.exe -c C:\myproj\wxdb003\dbeng.c -o obj\Debug\myproj\wxdb003\dbeng.o
windres.exe -IC:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\include -IC:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\lib\gcc_dll\mswud  -J rc -O coff -i C:\myproj\wxdb003\resource.rc -o obj\Debug\myproj\wxdb003\resource.res
mingw32-g++.exe -pipe -mthreads -D__GNUWIN32__ -D__WXMSW__ -DWXUSINGDLL -DwxUSE_UNICODE -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Winvalid-pch -include wx_pch.h -DWX_PRECOMP -Wall -g -D__WXDEBUG__ -IC:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\include -IC:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\lib\gcc_dll\mswud -c C:\myproj\wxdb003\wxdb003App.cpp -o obj\Debug\myproj\wxdb003\wxdb003App.o
mingw32-g++.exe -pipe -mthreads -D__GNUWIN32__ -D__WXMSW__ -DWXUSINGDLL -DwxUSE_UNICODE -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Winvalid-pch -include wx_pch.h -DWX_PRECOMP -Wall -g -D__WXDEBUG__ -IC:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\include -IC:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\lib\gcc_dll\mswud -c C:\myproj\wxdb003\wxdb003Main.cpp -o obj\Debug\myproj\wxdb003\wxdb003Main.o
mingw32-g++.exe -LC:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\lib\gcc_dll -o bin\Debug\wxdb003.exe obj\Debug\sqlite3\sqlite3.o obj\Debug\myproj\wxdb003\dbeng.o obj\Debug\myproj\wxdb003\wxdb003App.o obj\Debug\myproj\wxdb003\wxdb003Main.o  obj\Debug\myproj\wxdb003\resource.res -mthreads  -lwxmsw28ud -mwindows
Output file is bin\Debug\wxdb003.exe with size 1.38 MB
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 11 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 11 second(s))
```

Как видите, "обходное решение" проблемы я нашел - компилировать как CPP.

Можете объяснить, почему проект не собирается, когда для этого файла используется компилятор языка C (хотя код при этом вполне даже компилируется в OBJ) ?

Comment: Почитайте про `extern "C"` приведение имен к стандарту.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C и C++ по разному именуют экспортируемые символы. Если требуется компилировать именно как C и потом подключить к C++ то нужно явно указать это:

```
#ifndef DBENG_H_INCLUDED
#define DBENG_H_INCLUDED

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int dbinit(const char *dbname, char * errout);
int sqlexec(char *sqlexpr, char * errout, int (*p)(void*,int,char**,char**));
int dbclose();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif // DBENG_H_INCLUDED
```

В C макрос `__cplusplus` не определён и код внутри соответствующих макросов ни на что не влияет, а вот в C++ это явно укажет компилятору (`extern "C"`) использовать сишное соглашение об именование экспортируемых символов.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Действительно, в таком виде всё заработало.