# Можно ли метод класса С++ вызвать как функцию в коде на С?

Tags: c++, c, link

Допустим, есть C++ класс `A` с методом `B`, объявленный в файле `class_a.h`:

```
class A
{
    int B();
};
```

Определение этого класса находится в файле `class_a.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "class_a.h"
using namespace std;

int A::B()
{
    cout << "It works!" << endl;
}
```

Также есть код на C, например функция `main()` в файле `sample.c`, пытающаяся вызвать метод `A::B` как функцию:

```
int main()
{
    A::B();
    return 0;
}
```

Можно ли как то заставить эту конструкцию работать, компилируя файл `sample.c` компилятором языка С?

Comment: Вызвать нестатический метод класса "как обычную функцию" нельзя в принципе, ни в С, ни в С++. Поэтому непонятно в чем вообще суть вопроса: в "хакерском" вызова метода класса "как обычной функции", и в том, что вызов надо сделать имено из С. В чем?

Comment: В том, чтобы вызвать выполнение метода класса С++, как функции С из кода С.
Спасибо, что еще раз объяснили на счет статических функций. Теперь стало намного понятнее.

Comment: Основной проблемой "выполнения метода класса из С" будет способ выбора/передачи конкретного объекта, для которого этот метод надо выполнить.  Но у вас в вопросе об этом не сказано не слова. Более того, вы приняли ответ, в котором используется функция-*статический* член класса. То есть, оказывается, "метод класса" вам вообще был не нужен.

Comment: На счет передачи в функцию (указателя) на конкретный экземпляр объекта - это Вы "в самую точку" сказали. Я тоже думал, но не придумал, как это сделать. А больше, кроме статического метода никто ничего и не предлагал. Проще ведь сказать "невозможно", "невалидно" и т.п.

Comment: @AnT, конечная суть: адаптировать приведенную здесь: [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/682039/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%b7-c-%d0%b8-cpp-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-undefined-reference-to) функцию sqlexec(...) так, чтобы её аргумент int (*p)(void*,int,char**,char**) передавал sqlite3 API функции sqlite3_exec(...) указатель (callback) на метод конкретного экземпляра элемента GUI, заполняющий данными запроса этот элемент (напр. ListBox1).

Comment: Конкретная реализация callback метода у каждого (класса) элемента, должна быть, конечно же своя.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как минимум, ваш вызов не сработает даже в C++ - вызываемая функция-член не статическая.

Если вам нужен вызов статической функции - просто сделайте обертку - обычную функцию, видимую для C, наподобие

```
struct A {
    static int B();
};

extern "C" int wrapper() { return A::B(); }
```

Аналогично можно поступить и для нестатического члена - передавая указатель на объект, но как вы вообще собираетесь использовать этот указатель на **объект класса C++** в программе на C?

Comment: В конечном счете я хотел вызывать из кода С (обертки для sqlite) метод объекта С++, как callback функцию, чтобы например по такому вызову для конкретного экземпляра какого либо содержащего таблицу значений элемента GUI было наполнение этой таблицы из запроса sqlite.

Comment: Спасибо, что подсказали идею с оберткой!
Сработал вот такой код class_a.h:
<pre>
    #ifdef __cplusplus

    class A
    {
        public:
        static int B();
    };

    extern "C" int wrapper() { return A::B(); }

    #endif

    int wrapper();
</pre>

Comment: Поставил минус, так как не уверен, что это то, что нужно автору вопроса. По-моему, он не до конца разобрался с понятием статического члена, и столкнётся с проблемой вызова других методов при дальнейшей разработке. По-моему, он хотел проникнуть внутрь соглашения о вызовах [thiscall](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Соглашение_о_вызове#thiscall).